# Autolayout is sizing objects in a UIScrollView incorrectly

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, interface-builder, autolayout

I'm trying to create a layout using Interface Builder, size classes and a UIScrollView.

The UIScrollView is meant to be full screen, 0,0,0,0 left, top, right, bottom.

However when I set the constraints of my objects, (labels, textfields, etc) to be 20 away from the right size, it doesn't appear correctly in either Interface Builder or the simulator.

[image: The trailing constraint is obviously incorrect]

I've tried several things to fix this, putting the objects in a view container, making a new storyboard file etc and nothing has worked.

[image: This what happens when i try and force the UITextField to have the correct width, you can see what autolayout wants it to be]

[image: That gray UITextView should be 20 away from the right side]

Hopefully someone can figure out what is going on, I don't want to resort to springs and struts.

Comment: What does it mean, it doesn't look right? Can you show, how the objects are misplaced?

Comment: It's shown in the picture, that UITextView should be 20 away from the right edge. I'll add a picture of how it looks in the simulator.

Comment: I'm sorry, I also don't know what's going on there. Your constraints look right. Have you tried placing the object in a new storyboard file, just without the underlying scrollview? Would be intersting, if there's the same effect

Comment: Outside of a UIScrollView the label sizes correctly. So perhaps i'm setting up my UIScrollView incorrectly? But all i'm doing is 0,0,0,0 constraints on all four corners.

Comment: ok, the problem arises from the UIScrollView (and its at the moment undefinied content size). I've found the [following tutorial](http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/), where the positioning of elements within a uiscrollview with autolayout is explained. Hope it helps...